# Magento2 checkout problem

Tags: magento2, checkout

When i am adding product to my cart page this is working fine, also this is showing items on minicart. But when i am clicking on checkout this redirecting me to cart page and showing that `no products on cart`.

[image]

I am not getting what are the problems. Has anyone face this problem?? can you please tell me any solve??

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Can you please tell me about your magento varsion ?

Comment: magento 2!!!!!!

Comment: Magento 2 is okey but may i know somthing like 2.0.2 or 2.0.4 ?

Comment: Yes! this is 2.0.2

Comment: Check console error while checkout

Comment: On clicking on checkout its redirecting me to cart page! so i am unable to check that

Comment: In console have preserve log checkbox check it for chrom and Persist for mozila browser so you can able to check log

Comment: in every page i have this error "Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: null
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch"

Comment: @Aish Hira - I have add to cart product on your website, product view on mini cart and also it view in shopping cart. i am not getting the any issue. can you please give me steps or screen shot which you are follow.

Comment: now go to checkout

Comment: Website cart page checkout button not working but i am go to checkout by directly run checkout url, it is also working.

Comment: Then i am sorry to bother you ! but in my end everything is worng! what can be the problem?? I cleared my cache too

Comment: Are you go to checkout with customer login or not ?

Comment: without login!!

Comment: Try to clear browser cache and check it once.

Comment: i did this on private window

Comment: @Asish-hira I test your webpage, i could see the checkout/cart and the checkout perfectly.

Comment: Then thank you very much for your time! I posted it caz i am unable to see anything..

Comment: Im facing the similar issue in checkout/cart page..have posted here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127408/sales-order-payment-place-end-error-in-checkout-page-on-click-of-place-my-order

Comment: Hey Asish, have you overridden any sales payment event?